# How to Combine fields in AdoQuery sql statement in delphi?

Tags: delphi, ado

```
with AdoQuery do
   begin
     Close;
     SQL.Clear;
     SQL.Add('SELECT (name+' '+surname+' '+father) as initihal, address from user');
     Open;
   end;
```

How to add **space** between **name surname and father** ?
 i want to see result in DbGrid like that

Lionel Andrés Messi

Comment: Please don't tag-spam,  The answer to this doesn't depend on the Delphi version.

Answer (score 0):

The ADO layer/backend server should be fine with returning a column value which is an expression including a number of column values and string literals.

As you are trying to construct your SQL statement in Delphi source code (rarely a good idea, ime) you need to express what you want in a way which is syntactically correct from the compiler's point of view, as well as producing the desired result from your RDMS.  To do this, all of the single quotes inside `SQL.Add(...)` **except** the outer two need to be doubled-up, otherwise you will get a syntax error on compilation.

However, even once you've done that,  your SQL still may not execute correctly at run-time depending on whether your naming of the columns in your result-set is digestible by your back-end server.  It's best to create and test your `Select` statement using whatever query tool is available for your RDMS, then attempt to set it up in Delphi only **after** you've got it working correctly from the RDMS's pov.

Btw, you will encounter fewer problems if you get into the habit of using the `QuotedStr` function in constructing the column values you want - you obviously need the syntax practice so I leave you to look that up in the Online Help.

Also, if you need to constrain the result set by specifying a `Where` clause, be sure to do it in a way which minimizes the risk of Sql Injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which arises when the SQL includes input text from the user.  The bet way to do this is to use a parameterized `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If using inline SQL you have escape the quote characters or use a function that returns spaces. You will not be able to update the result. Another option is to add a calculated field in your Delphi ADOQuery component and do the combine client side in OnCalcFields.

```
with AdoQuery do
   begin
     Close;
     SQL.Clear;
     SQL.Add('SELECT name+'' ''+surname+'' ''+father as initihal, address from user');
     Open;
   end;
```

If using SQL Server for a database you can use the space() function.

```
with AdoQuery do
   begin
     Close;
     SQL.Clear;
     SQL.Add('SELECT name+ space(1) + surname+ space(1) +father as initihal, address from user');
     Open;
   end;
```